# Inflate a xml on linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I try to explain my problem in points.

- I have a linear layout in **xml_1** which contains buttons.
- I have a **xml_2** which contains textview and many other views.
- I want to inflate **xml_2** on linear layout of **xml_1.**

I tried this:-
`

```
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  View inflatedView;
  linear_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);//in xml_1

  layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
  inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_2, linear_layout, false);
  linear_layout.addView(inflatedView);
```

Issue is xml_2 gets inflated over linear_layout of xml_1 but buttons that already present in linear_layout of xml_1 do not get remove,instead xml_2 added in right of button of linear_layout of xml_1.

thanks

Comment: if Doug answer won't enough for you, please provide more info so I can guide you better.

Comment: if I remove my inflated layout then my buttons on linear_layout of xml_1 also removed (if i follow below answer).But I want that if i remove my inflated layout(xml_2) then same xml_1 will be shown as ever before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the contents of linear_layout, do this after you inflate it:

```
linear_layout.removeAllViews();
```

Then you can add new views to it.

Comment: by doing this, if I remove my inflated layout ,then I dont restore my buttons on linear_layout in xml_1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because you set an orientation to your LinearLayout from xml_1. As you said,

> instead xml_2 added in right of button of linear_layout of xml_1.

That's probably because your LinearLayout has `android:orientation="horizontal"`, so when you `addView`, it's going to be added according to your orientation.

If you want to add xml_2 in xml_1 and xml_2 is UNDER the button you have in xml_1, wrap another LinearLayout in it:

```
<!--Inflate your views and put them inside this one-->
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:height="wrap_content
         android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

That way, your xml_2 will be UNDER the views you ALREADY have in the LinearLayout.

I am not sure that is what you wanted, comment further if it's something else.